# Getting 503 Bad Sequence after entering username

Tags: ftp

I have an FTP Server on a device, with user name: xyz. Before performing ftp, i have done nmap to check if the port 21 is open and it is. The device is accepting connections on port 21.
I do an ftp to the device and enter the user name and immediately the server responds with 503 Bad Commands.

I searched a lot, but could not get an answer. Please help me in this regard.

here are the tcp stream:

220 FTP Server Connected.

USER xyz

503 Bad sequence of commands

Thanks,
Ravi.

Comment: What does the FTP server tell you when you ask it for `help`?